# Javafx doesn't detect changes of available printers

Tags: java, dynamic, javafx, printing

I'm developing a JavaFX application, which involves printers. But I need to make an update button so that the application can detect recently created or deleted printers (disconnected or connected) while the application is running.

## PS :

`Printer.getAllPrinters()` gets what I want but it needs the application to be restarted before detecting changes, which means that my update button is useless.

edit 1:

```
public void updateAvailablePrinters() {
    printers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableSet<Printer> allPrinters = Printer.getAllPrinters();
    allPrinters.forEach(printer -> printers.add(printer)); // printers is a field variable
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the faulty code? Does it throw any errors (i.e. a stack trace to share)?

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE added Code samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [lookupPrintServices method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html#lookupPrintServices%28javax.print.DocFlavor,%20javax.print.attribute.AttributeSet%29) of `javax.print.PrintServiceLookup` instead of JavaFX `Printer` to display the available printer services.

I just used the following snippet to get the list of available printers, and it seems it detects added/removed printers while the `Application` is running.

```
System.out.println("Print services: " + printServices.length);

for (PrintService printer : printServices)
    System.out.println("Printer: " + printer.getName());
```

Or if you just want to make the user able to select a printer before the actual printing, you could use [showPrintDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PrinterJob.html#showPrintDialog-javafx.stage.Window-) of `PrinterJob` as in the dialog the printer list is also refreshed:

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(stage)){
    boolean success = job.printPage(stage.getScene().getRoot());
    if (success) {
        job.endJob();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with showPrintDialog is, that it doesn't show if a printer is online.

Answer (score 1):

From the API-Doc of [Printer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/Printer.html) class:

> Since the availability of printers may change during the execution of
>   a program, due to administrative actions, a long running program which
>   has cached a printer which has since been taken off-line, may create a
>   job using that instance, but printing will fail.

So it seems that there is no easy way of doing it in JavaFX. What you can do is, try to print and watch the PrintJob.JobStatus, if it fails, the printer is offline or not installed anymore. After that you are able to choose another printer.

Comment: A good workaround but in efficient, lets say I'm in options screen and then the update button is pressed and done your workaround then The printer might print something if it's connected and online .

Comment: @AbdElraoufSabri There isn't a good workaround. Reading available Printers is a native method, so it's OS-dependant. So printing will be treated differently. In Windows you got a PrintQueue were each Job will be scheduled, even if the printer is acutally not connected. So, maybe in your case the user should be able to select the (active) printer manually, like in other applications.

Comment: ok thanks . So apparently I'm going to remove the update button as it's useless :)